# ABAddressBook how do I set the group of a returned ABRecordRef?

Tags: ios, xcode, abaddressbook

So I'm calling this method:

```
- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController*)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

Which returns an ABRecordRef. But I can't see it to a group using ABGroupAddMember.

If I create an ABRecordRef manually I can set the group, but can't with the returned *person* object from the delegate method.

For example, this code works (borrowed from a post on here, can't find link):

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

// create address book record
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
// create a person  
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();  
// first name of the new person
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"FirstName" , nil);
// his last name 
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"LastName", nil);  
//add the new person to the record
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil); 

ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate(); //create a group 
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"My Group", &error); // set group's name 
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error); // add the group   
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

ABGroupAddMember(group, person, &error); // add the person to the group         
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

//save the record
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil);  

// relase the ABRecordRef  variable
CFRelease(person);
```

How do I make that code work with the returned Person ABRecordRef object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so fixed it (sometimes asking the question clears your mind to solve it)

```
int i = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
ABRecordRef p = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook,i);
```

Correctly creating a new ABRecordRef seems to fix the problem. No idea why. Maybe someone can say why you need to recast it?